# How to type nested objects - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a probem with typing this line of code initialState[a][b].

I got this error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ food: { pizza: boolean; chicken: boolean; }; transport: { bus: boolean; car: boolean; }; }'

```
function testTypescript(a: string, b: string) {
    const initialState = {
        food: {
            pizza: false,
            chicken: false,
        },
        transport: {
            bus: false,
            car: false,
        },
    };
    const newData = !initialState[a][b]; // How can I type this line?
    const newState = { ...initialState, [a]: newData };
    return newState;
}
```

Comment: Your state object has properties with defined keys, so you can’t use *any string* as an object’s key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some generics. [Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQUoDMD2eAJgFzpbZRgCWAXjfKQEYEA2E8AdgNznYDGACyp8A1hA5NW7buQC+PcsABOnAM5g8S4KUwUojAK6rJeNpx56+8JSbMzssjI4w4DHPsCp4OUJKuAAKuAQqnxKVGDAADwBUBAAHkgchKpQYiB4OLAISAB8ABQMUAEANPqk6ZnZiBAA2gEAugCUZJbe-lBUHFSe8CxwNaQDSFCounoU+EQ6vBN61HRFOH2qECWzc-xCouKkyyyr65tQskebymoaWjPHeobGuCtrG5tWNo8Hz8ens-KzfO1gFAOBAAO4AEUQ8FGUAAhF0elQ+sM6vAGrVGA0uFAAPQ4qAACTwoKgVh8AElfMFfEJUiwuhAAPz-QHAsEomFoKAAOl5CN6-RyaygtTRpBBEKhJwsFCUEGABiUPglKJ4zjxUAAAsBVABaBKQDz6pRKTQYPyBYKhcKRfIAcg4eECAggcrtZTtADc+gYIHamhgMBrtXqDRAja7TUpzSFLZBrRFgPapoR3VA7eE+H6AzH-EF42FE-aLhx1JpgGm7fd-UA)

```
type State = {
  food: {
    pizza: boolean;
    chicken: boolean;
  };

  transport: {
    bus: boolean;
    car: boolean;
  }
}

function testTypescript<T extends keyof State>(a: T, b: keyof State[T]) {
    const initialState: State = {
        food: {
            pizza: false,
            chicken: false,
        },
        transport: {
            bus: false,
            car: false,
        },
    };
    const newData = !initialState[a][b]; // How can I type this line?
    const newState = { ...initialState, [a]: newData };
    return newState;
}

// @ts-expect-error
testTypescript('notThere', 'value')

// @ts-expect-error
testTypescript('food', 'rice')

testTypescript('transport', 'bus')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function testTypescript(a: string, b: string) {
    const initialState: { [a: string]: { [b: string]: boolean; } } = {
        food: {
            pizza: false,
            chicken: false,
        },
        transport: {
            bus: false,
            car: false,
        },
    };
    const newData: boolean = !initialState[a][b];
    const newState = { ...initialState, [a]: { [b]: newData } };
    return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any nesting

```
type initial = {
  [key: string] :  any;
}

function testTypescript(a: string, b: string) {
    const initialState : initial = {
        food: {
            pizza: false,
            chicken: false,
        },
        transport: {
            bus: false,
            car: false,
        },
    };
    const newData = !initialState[a][b]; // How can I type this line?
    const newState = { ...initialState, [a]: newData };
    return newState;
}
```